# Performance of pandas GroupBy to the Keys

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have to group a Dataframe and do some more calculations by using the keys as input parameter. Doing so I figured out some strange performance behavior. 
The time for grouping is ok and the time to get the keys too. But if I execute both steps it takes 24x the time.

Am I using it wrong or is there another way to get the unique parameter pairs with all their indices?

Here is some easy example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def test_1(df):
    grouped = df.groupby(['up','down'])
    return grouped

def test_2(grouped):
    keys = grouped.groups.keys()
    return keys

def test_3(df):
    keys = df.groupby(['up','down']).groups.keys()    
    return keys

def test_4(df):
    grouped = df.groupby(['up','down'])    
    keys = grouped.groups.keys()
    return keys

n = np.arange(1,10,1)
df = pd.DataFrame([],columns=['up','down'])
df['up'] = n
df['down'] = n[::-1]

grouped = df.groupby(['up','down'])

%timeit test_1(df)
169 µs ± 12.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit test_2(grouped)
1.01 µs ± 70.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit test_3(df)
4.36 ms ± 210 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit test_4(df)
4.2 ms ± 161 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Thanks in advance for comments or ideas.